# How to cast an object for a method call?

Tags: c#, methods, casting

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public class AI {
    public AI() { }
    public virtual void Update(float frameTime) { }
}

public class Boss : AI {
    public Boss() : base() { }
    public override void Update(float frameTime) { 
        Console.WriteLine("Boss Update"); 
    }
}
```

I have a Character that holds an AI variable that I then store a Boss instance in and try to cast it as such to get the Boss's Update function rather than the base class's.

```
AI ai = new Boss();
(Boss)ai.Update(0f);
```

This doesn't work though, what is the proper method for doing this in C#? It was properly working with another AI class where I didn't even *have* to cast it at all, it just ran the right version of Update, so I must have changed something unintentionally.

Comment: you need to wrap double "((" when casting to a Class ((Boss)ai.Update();

Comment: A cast is not necessary in order to call the Update method on the Boss class because you've marked the method as `virtual` in the AI class, and you've specified `override` in the Boss class. By the way, I notice that the code you've posted won't compile.

Comment: Update(float) should take a variable, but your example is not passing one. Is your problem that it won't even compile or was that a typo?

Comment: @JasonDown: It won't compile for that reason as well as trying to cast `void` to an instance of `Boss`.  Also, the call to the parameterless `base` constructor is unnecessary.

Comment: @Ed S.: The code example should be one of those puzzles. `Find all of the things that are wrong with this picture.`

Comment: @JasonDown: Yeah, we all start somewhere.  I just didn't "get" polymorphism at all until I had a real world use case for it and a subsequent "Ah HA!" moment.  It's very abstract and hard to appreciate when simply told what it is.  Kind of like explaining a majestic view to a blind person.  It just isn't the same.

Comment: @EdS.: Yes, I agree. Not too long ago I entered the world of dependency injection. Everything seemed backwards to how I thought you were supposed to do things and my code looked like it was written by a ferret on LSD.

Comment: This is just a simplified version of the code so that it's simpler to ask about, so telling me that I made a typo on arbitrary code doesn't help.
@Dr. Wily's Apprentice: It's overridden in the actual code and yet it still runs the `AI.Update()` rather than `Boss.Update()`.
The issue it was giving me was that it was running the base `Update` rather than the `Boss` version.

Comment: @Shawn - Well, all I'm trying to tell you is that the `virtual` keyword and the `override` keyword are intended to do exactly what you're saying you want to do, and it looks like you've used them correctly.  If you find that it isn't working, then the problem is elsewhere.  Perhaps you're accidentally calling a different overload method of "Update".  Perhaps your current code doesn't compile, and you're accidentally running the previously successfully compiled version of the code.

Comment: @Shawn: Well, the code that you post as an example actually is extremely relevant, and if your example code was semantically the same as your real code then `Boss.Update` would definitely have been called, so obviously this example was insufficient.  How can we presume to know what is and is not relevant other than by using your own example?

Comment: @EdS.: I'll take that into account next time. My apologies. And it's still giving me weird results but I'll figure it out, just waiting for the facepalm moment.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [dot operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zhxzbds.aspx) has [higher precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) than casting, so your code is being interpreted as:

```
(Boss)(ai.Update(frameTime));
```

You need to add an extra pair of parentheses to get what you want:

```
((Boss)ai).Update(frameTime);
```

However it shouldn't be necessary to perform this cast since your method is virtual.

You may also want to consider changing your `AI` type to be an `abstract class` or (if possible) an interface.

Comment: Of course, the cast isn't needed at all as `Update` is virtual and overriden in the `Boss` class.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to add parens around the cast and the cast object to call the method on the cast value (i.e., `((SomeType)someObj).SomeMethod()`), but that is beside the point as the cast is completely unnecessary.

`Update` is virtual and the call is polymorphic, so even though the `ai` variable was declared as an instance of `AI` it will actually call `Boss.Update()` as that's what the type really is behind the scenes.

This is exactly why polymorphism is powerful.  You don't have to know what the underlying type is to get the correct, implementation specific behavior.

Comment: +1 for going into more detail about why the cast is unnecessary.

Comment: Ya +1. Time to kybosh my own answer (an inadequate version of yours!).

Answer (score 0):

What your line of code is saying:

```
AI ai = new Boss();
(Boss)ai.Update();
```

is take what is returned from `Update();` and cast it to type `Boss`

what you need to do is

```
AI ai = new Boss();
((Boss)ai).Update();
```

which is cast `ai` to type Boss and call the `Update()` method.